# Element from id via get request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a get request with jquery to a domain and trying to get an image from it. I know the element id which is "image-iframe". I looked up this and only could find $("id").attr("src") which does not work for me since I am not looking for it in my page.

```
$.get(Link,function(data){
    var link = $(data).find('image-iframe').attr("src")
})
```

this is the best I could think of with my very small knowledge of js/jquery

Comment: What are you trying to do there? You can manipulate DOM elements with jQuery, but not in a response string or whatever ...

Comment: `.find('image-iframe')` doesn't look for an element with ID "image-iframe". It does look for an element with **tag** "image-iframe". If you want to find an element by ID, use ID selector: `.find('#image-iframe')`.

Comment: I am currently just trying to assign the image link from the element id to a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code.

```
 $.get(Link,function(data){
        var link = $(data).find('#image-iframe').attr("src")
    })
```

Id should access via $('#ID')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Id** : $('#YourElementId')

**Class** : $('.YourElementClass')

**Tag**: $('YourElement')

```
$.get(Link,function(data){
    var link = $(data).find('#YourElementId').attr("ElementAttributes")
})
```